# Sublime 3 error installing package control

Tags: sublimetext3, package-control

I am trying to install package control in Sublime Text editor 3 on `Ubuntu 14.04` . I follow simple instruction from https://sublime.wbond.net/installation.

But I get follow error:

```
Package Control: Error downloading channel. b'curl: (7) Failed to connect to sublime.wbond.net port 443: Network is unreachable' downloading https://sublime.wbond.net/channel.json.
error: Package Control
```

Comment: @drukaman Please see my answer and edit below. Hopefully getting rid of all the old files and installing from the master git repo will help, otherwise follow the instructions to submit an issue. Good luck!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Go back to the [installation page](https://sublime.wbond.net/installation) and follow the instructions in the [***`Manual`***](https://sublime.wbond.net/installation#Manual) section:

1. Click the `Preferences > Browse Packages…` menu
2. Browse up a folder and then into the `Installed Packages/` folder
3. Download [Package Control.sublime-package](https://sublime.wbond.net/Package%20Control.sublime-package) and copy it into the `Installed Packages/` directory
4. Restart Sublime Text

This should install Package Control for you without any problems.

**EDIT**

Please read through this issue [here](https://github.com/wbond/package_control/issues/723), and follow wbond's [instructions](https://github.com/wbond/package_control/issues/723#issuecomment-56665624) to install from git. First, completely quit Sublime, then remove **all** traces of Package Control - any folders in `~/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages`, any files in `~/.config/sublime-text-3/Installed Packages`, the folder `~/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/User/Package Control.cache`, and any files in `~/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/User` that start with `Package Control.*` - `Package Control.last-run`, `Package Control.sublime-settings`, `Package Control.system-ca-bundle`, and anything else you can find.

Next, assuming you have `git` installed (run `sudo apt-get install git` if you don't), switch to `~/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages` and run

```
git clone https://github.com/wbond/package_control.git "Package Control"
```

to clone the master repo (make sure you've completely quit Sublime before running this). Restart Sublime and see if everything installs properly. If not, [follow the instructions for creating a debug log](https://github.com/wbond/package_control/blob/master/contributing.md), restart Sublime to generate the log, open the Console by selecting **`View -> Show Console`**, then copy the **entire contents** (it'll be a lot) into a new file. Open a [new issue](https://github.com/wbond/package_control/issues/new) and describe **exactly** what the problem is, including all the details above and the fact that you just installed from the master branch, and paste in the contents of the debug log (make sure you put it in a code block by adding triple backticks ``` before and after). Will Bond (wbond) should get in touch with some suggestions.

Good luck!

---

Note for users of other operating systems: I'm not sure if this is a Linux-only problem or not, but in case it isn't, Mac users will find `Packages` and `Installed Packages` in `~/Library/Application Settings/Sublime Text 3`, while Windows users with standard (i.e., non-portable installs) will find them in your user directory under `AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3`. For Windows portable installs, the directories should be in your install directory under `Data`.

Comment: I have also tried following step but it don't work too... When I make debug: true. I got following error : Error trying to parse settings: Unexpected trailing characters in Packages/User/Package Control.sublime-settings:1:8.

Comment: I am still getting same problem when I follow manual instruction. Following error comes every time.. Package Control: Error downloading channel. b'curl: (7) Failed to connect to sublime.wbond.net port 443: Network is unreachable' downloading https://sublime.wbond.net/channel.json.
error: Package Control

Comment: I can't thank you enough for this. Everything else failed on a fresh install of Sublime text 3. Only this worked. Thank you.

Comment: https://github.com/wbond/package_control/blob/master/contributing.md  link ended up with 404.

Answer (score 9):

For the sublime text version 3126 onward Package Control is disabled by default. Just go to `Preferences > Settings` and remove Package Control from the `ignored_packages` setting.

Comment: i am in 3207 and can;t see it in ignore package!

Comment: THANK YOU! I wasted several hours reading ridiculous support request and installing different python versions, when THIS was the cause. How that setting was suddenly enabled when everything was working correctly yesterday is a different matter. Just ... amazing.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem on Linux Mint 18.1 (Ubuntu derivative), and after reading a few posts here and there, it occurred to me that something had likely become corrupted, so I: 1) uninstalled sublime; AND then 2) deleted everything related to sublime from "/home/thom/.config/". Step 2 was the real key. Then I reinstalled sublime according to "apt" section [HERE](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/linux_repositories.html). Once reinstalled, package control was able to install without error.